# Добавить содержимое кнопки в div

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Имею вот такой код виртуальной клавиатуры, не как не могу написать скрипт так что бы при нажатии на кнопку(класс key) её содержимое выводилась на экран, это div с классом display.
В теории есть понимание что нужно использовать querySelectorAll,  цикл for of, и textContent.
Но что то не как не соображу как это всё между собой подружить.

```html
<h1 class="visually-hidden">Виртуальная клавиатура</h1>
<section class="computer">
  <div class="display-wrapper">
    <div class="display"></div>
  </div>
  <button class="button clear" type="button">Очистить</button>
</section>

<section class="keyboard">
  <div class="keyboard-line">
    <button class="button key" type="button" id="index_0">й</button>
    <button class="button key" type="button" id="index_1">ц</button>
    <button class="button key" type="button" id="index_2">у</button>
    <button class="button key" type="button" id="index_3">к</button>
    <button class="button key" type="button" id="index_4">е</button>
    <button class="button key" type="button" id="index_5">н</button>
    <button class="button key" type="button" id="index_6">г</button>
    <button class="button key" type="button" id="index_7">ш</button>
    <button class="button key" type="button" id="index_8">щ</button>
    <button class="button key" type="button" id="index_9">з</button>
    <button class="button key" type="button" id="index_10">х</button>
    <button class="button key" type="button" id="index_11">ъ</button>
  </div>
  <div class="keyboard-line">
    <button class="button key space" type="button" id="index_33"> </button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: изучить что такое события в javascript https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events

Answer (score 0):

Как то так.

```
  let btn = document.querySelectorAll('.key'),
    display = document.querySelector('.display');

  btn.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
      display.textContent += item.textContent;
    });
  });
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]